# Cannot update background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

**Code**:

```
var imgurl = 'img/star.png';
$("#venueId-"+nid).css('background','url("'+imgurl+'") no-repeat top right');
```

This is the beginning of a function that occurs on click. The desired result is that the image (`img/star.png`) appears in the top-right corner of the div. Unfortunately, when this script occurs, nothing happens.

I have double-checked the relative location of the image, and when changing the background to a gradient I had no troubles with this code.

Comment: Without much context, have you checked to see if the browser is making a request for any `star.png`? It might be that it is not relative to where you think you are. Beyond that, you should probably ensure that `"#venueId-" + nid` actually evaluates to something because JQuery will silently fail if it does not.

Comment: Does the DOM node's `style` value changes? Does it work if you hardcode it in html?

Comment: @pickypg, `"#venueId-" + nid` is fine. @zerkms, I had no issue when using the same code to change the background to a gradient. The issue has only arisen when trying to use an image via url.

Comment: You'll need to more information -- debug the problem, already!  Does the element change in DOM inspector? Can you make the BG appear with the same CSS on a static element? Find out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gJLdt/ here I just put it in jsfiddle with some random picture ... and it works ... so it must be something else not the part that you are showing us

Comment: Replace the code with this: `$("#venueID-"+nid).css('background','-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(158,221,0,1) 0%,rgba(138,182,107,0.56) 44%,rgba(57,130,53,0) 100%)');` and it works, with the only difference being calling an image url. The element does not change in DOM inspector.

Comment: did you look into my jsfiddle? i used your code ... and it works! maybe in your case you somehow don't see the actual right top corner of the div, but just the rest? it is hard to guess from the part that you showed us.

Comment: I saw @MartinTurjak, but it doesn't not work in my code! And there is nothing else that interferes with it, as it was only an update of very similar code that worked fine.

Comment: then reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle ... and we can have a look? cause I can not really help if I don't see a little bit more.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uGAWn/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html has `id="venueId"` and you are calling `$("#venueID-")`. Also it is wraped into a function ... and you don't call the function anywhere.

According to your jsfiddle.

So I just fixed this two things in your jsfiddle and it works now ... I also moved the width and height from html to the css.

[jsfiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/uGAWn/2/)

**Edit:** You can try writing everything in jQuery like this:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGAWn/5/)

or if you want to have it your way, I would change it a little bit. You could maybe use onclick instead of calling javascript in href. And I would use function expression (`foo = function(){}`) instead of function declaration (`function foo(){}`). [here is some more on that](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGAWn/6/)

**An alternative:**

if you would want to apply the background through a class selector (here the url gets hardcoded in the css), you could do it like this (this is now in practice what Swordfish0321 talks about):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGAWn/7/)

Comment: The jsfiddle is an example but not my exact code. Yes you are correct, however my code function still does not work - [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGAWn/4/) you see what I am trying to do - on click, have the background image change.

Comment: here is an update, where I just use jQuery to do everything, without calling the inline function. http://jsfiddle.net/uGAWn/5/ It is more elegant, since you are already using jQuery.

Comment: This worked, but the real issue was that I had a conflicting line of code a few moments after this. But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open firebug(Firefox) or Inspect Element(chrome), switch to "Net" tab, and refresh your page, now you can see if the 'img/star.png' file is successfully loaded or not.

If it says '404 Not Found', the path this this image is wrong;
If it says '403 Forbidden', the permission of this image is not suitable, make sure the nginx/apache user can read it.

Comment: It's not loaded at all. There is no request sent out for it at all visible in Network tab.

Comment: Double check DOM node's style, see what happens to it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be that guy that says  "you should do it this way", but rather than piece together some jquery concatenation of CSS. You might want to just create a CSS class and then toggle it with jquery. This will result in cleaner execution and more testable code since now you are separating responsibilities.

Comment: I agree with you +1, although his approach suggests that he might want to do something dynamic with the image urls before applying them.

Comment: @MartinTurjak totes. But there are ways to clean this up nonetheless, perhaps only adding this dynamic URL and storing all the other CSS bg-related properties in the stylesheet.

Comment: totes back again ;-) Yet another way, the way I would do it, is using LESS or Sass ... and then have all the stuff in the CSS and just use class selectors, but this might be a bit out of the scope of OP's question already.